# Session, FormsAuthenticationTicket, store data about the user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-authentication, asp.net-cache

I'm building a web application that needs to be able to scale.

We want to store a connection string, an object that says what organization the user is working on right now and the identity of the user.

We could serialize down this and send through the userdata property in the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`, but that feels to not be the optimal solution, because it is 4-5 strings of data that are unncessesary, but the main issue is that we are sending an encrypted connectionstring to the user which we don't want to.

So what are our options?

Can ASP.NET cache be our solution? Can we couple the expiration of the ASP.NET cache and the formsauthenticationcookie?

Comment: Session should be your solution. Read [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: These Stack&nbsp;Overflow questions relating to scaling the ASP.NET session may well prove useful: - [Scaling up the ASP.NET session state server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488748/scaling-up-the-asp-net-session-state-server) - [Scaling an ASP.NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549841/scaling-an-asp-net-application)